# getView() (for a Custom ListView ) doesn't get called on notifyDatasetChanged()

Tags: android

I have the following problem, and searched for a while but haven't got any solution from the net:

I have a custom list view, each item has the following layout (I just post the essential):

```
<LinearLayout>
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/friendlist_iv_avatar" />
 <TextView andorid:id="@+id/friendlist_tv_nick_name" />
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/friendlist_iv_status_icon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I have a class FriendRowItem, which is inflated from the above layout:

```
public class FriendRowItem extends LinearLayout{

 private ImageView ivAvatar;
 private ImageView ivStatusIcon;
 private TextView tvNickName;

 public FriendRowItem(Context context) {
  super(context);
  RelativeLayout friendRow = (RelativeLayout) Helpers.inflate(context, R.layout.friendlist_row);
  this.addView(friendRow);
  ivAvatar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.friendlist_iv_avatar);
  ivStatusIcon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.friendlist_iv_status_icon);
  tvNickName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.friendlist_tv_nick_name);

 }

 public void setPropeties(Friend friend) {
  //Avatar
  ivAvatar.setImageResource(friend.getAvatar().getDrawableResourceId());

  //Status
  Status.Type status  = friend.getStatusType();
  if ( status == Type.ONLINE) {
   ivStatusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.online_icon);
  } else {
   ivStatusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.offline_icon);
  }

  //Nickname
  String name = friend.getChatID();
  if ( friend.hasName()) {
   name = friend.getName();
  }
  tvNickName.setText(name);
 }

}
```

In the main activity, I have a custom listview: lvMainListView, with an custom adapter (whose class extends ArrayAdapter  - and off course: override the method getView ), the data set of the adapter is: `ArrayList<Friend> friends`:

```
private class FriendRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend>  { 

  public FriendRowAdapter(Context applicationContext, int friendlistRow,
    ArrayList<Friend> friends) {
   super(applicationContext, friendlistRow, friends);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
   Friend friend = getItem(position);
   FriendRowItem row = (FriendRowItem) convertView;
   if ( row == null ) {
    row = new FriendRowItem(ShowFriendsList.this.getApplicationContext());
   }
   row.setPropeties( friend );
   return row;
  }
 }
```

- the problem is when I change the status of a friend from OFFLINE to ONLINE, then call notifyDataSetChanged(), nothing happens : the status icon of that friend doesn't change.
  I tried debugging, and saw the code: notifyDataSetChanged() get called, but the custom getView() is not fired !

Can you please tell me, that is normal in Android, or did I do something wrong ? (I am using Android 1.5).

Thank you in advance,
Son

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am sorry,
 I have just found out: because I called the the method notifyDatasetChanged() in another thread (In fact, I am using Smack API to develop a chat client - and the method notifyDatasetChanged() is get called in a listener of smack, which in turn is run in another thread ).
The correct solution: notifyDatasetChanged should be called like this:

```
    lvFriendList.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();         
        }
    });
```

I hope this will spare somebody time, if they meet the same problem :).

Comment: Thx, you saved me some hours of rage :)

Comment: Does this mean that I have to do this below as well?

 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isSearchItemNotFound) {



                            mAgendaAdapterObj.notifyDataSetChanged();


                            mAgendaRv.setAdapter(mAgendaAdapterObj);

          }

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You need to add

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return YOURLIST.length;
}
```

in the your adapter file