# Array Adapter doesn't call GetView

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

I wrote Loader class which implements AsyncResponse:

```
public class Loader implements AsyncResponse {
public Activity contextActivity;

Loader(Activity context) {
    this.contextActivity = context;
}
```

Class "Loader" has method "DrawTabInfo" which calling from AsyncResponse callback.

```
public void drawTabInfo(String jsonBlob, int tabId)
{
    JSONObject dataJsonObj;
    PullToRefreshListView list = null;

    try {
        dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonBlob);
        JSONArray jsonData = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("steals");

        ArrayList<JSONObject> data = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        for (int i=0;i<jsonData.length();i++){
            data.add(jsonData.getJSONObject(i));

        }
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(contextActivity, data);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contextActivity);

        if (tabId == 0) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewlayout, null, false);
            list = (PullToRefreshListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        }
        if (tabId == 1) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewlayout2, null, false);
            list = (PullToRefreshListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        }

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

Log.d("COUNT") shows - "4", what means array is built fine.

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<JSONObject> profiles;
    public String header;
    public String preText;
    public String imageURL;

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView header;
        public ImageView image;
        public TextView preText;
        public LinearLayout linearItemLayout;
    }

    public Adapter(Activity context, ArrayList<JSONObject> array) {
        super(context, R.layout.tab1_list_layout, array);
        Log.d("ADAPTER", "SETTING ADAPTER");
        this.context = context;
        this.profiles = array;
        Log.d("COUNT", "" + profiles.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return profiles.size();
    }
```

My getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    Log.i("GetView Log", "Adapters GetView hasbeen called");// thats never calling

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_list_layout, null);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.linearItemLayout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.linearItemLayout);
        viewHolder.header = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemHeader);
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemPreImage);
        viewHolder.preText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemPreText);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    JSONObject item = null;

    try {
        item = profiles.get(position);
        header = item.getString("header");
        preText = item.getString("previewText");
        imageURL = item.getString("previewImageUrl");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("ADAPTER LOG", header);

    holder.header.setText(header);
    holder.preText.setText(preText);

    int headerHeight = (int) Math.round(header.length() * 1.5);
    holder.linearItemLayout.setMinimumHeight(40 + headerHeight + preText.length());

    Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    Picasso.with(context).load(imageURL).resize(140,100).into(holder.image);

    return rowView;
}
```

In MainActivity i calling, where "this" = MainActivity;

```
    Loader loader = new Loader(this);
    loader.loadTabInfo(0);
```

Method getView never calling. What I'am doing wrong?

**UPD:**

Solved:

```
public void drawTabInfo(String jsonBlob, int tabId)
{
    JSONObject dataJsonObj;
    PullToRefreshListView list = null;

    try {
        dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonBlob);
        JSONArray jsonData = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("steals");

        ArrayList<JSONObject> data = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        for (int i=0;i<jsonData.length();i++){
            data.add(jsonData.getJSONObject(i));

        }
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(contextActivity, data);

        //LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contextActivity);

        if (tabId == 0) {
            //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewlayout, null, false);
            list = (PullToRefreshListView) contextActivity.findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Comment: Check the import statements of **Adapter**. There is an Adapter interface in Android, so better change your adapter class name to **MyAdapter** and check.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine .. just you need a little bit change in get view method
add a return statement.. like `return rowView;`

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    Log.d("GETVIEaW", "GETVIEW");

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_list_layout, null);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.linearItemLayout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.linearItemLayout);
            viewHolder.header = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemHeader);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemPreImage);
            viewHolder.preText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemPreText);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
        else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.preText.setText("Type your name");

        return rowView;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but return statement is already in get view method :)

Comment: Log.d("GETVIEaW", "GETVIEW") - this not calling

Comment: please see the edited ans.... add else statement and set some text or image with your textview or imageview

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `Log.d()` is not called? You may want to change logging scope, usually default scope is `info` and it doesn't show debug messages. You can try to use `Log.i()` or change scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try posting your `adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);` to handler. Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563262/getview-for-a-custom-listview-doesnt-get-called-on-notifydatasetchanged#answer-4563476)